# In MOSS 2010 how to enable the Content and Structure "Checked Out to Me" view to work!!! Help Please!

Tags: 2010

I am working on a site where the user has Full Control on a Sub-site and is trying to access the "Checked Out to Me" under the Site Action -> Site Settings -> Content and Structure interface. The issue the user is having is that they can not take the view off the Default View into the "Checked Out to Me" view. This option is not working and stays on the default view. Is there a way to turn on this option without changing the permissions on the parent or destroying the sub-site. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I tried the same in my development environment and it works fine for me. Can you tell me how you have implemented the permissions for the user in the sub site?

Comment: The permissions for the users in the sub-site are contributor permissions. In the parent site they have a limited read only access. On the parent site it works fine but on the sub-site it does not work at all.